# Draw an Ellipse in 4326

Tags: postgis

I have a problem drawing an ellipse in PostGIS and 4326 system.

My parameters are:

```
"geography" : {"type":"Ellipse",
                    "smallSide":100,
                    "bigSide" : 110,
                    "rotation" : 0,
                    "coordinates":[8.54736328125,46.37156925087649]}
```

[image]

Searching on web (stack overflow) I came up to a solution that is close to my request but I have some problem with Scale and Translate.

```
ST_AsEWKT(ST_Translate( ST_Rotate( ST_Scale( ST_Buffer(ST_Point(8.54736328125,46.37156925087649)::geography, 3000)::geometry, 0.3,0.5)::geometry, 0), 8.54736328125,46.37156925087649))
```

The center is set in Switzerland.

This function has 2 big problem: 
1. The Ellipse is not centered in the original coords; 
2. I don't know how to convert xFactor/yFactor of Scale to match meters parameters;

I've tried to split the function to check where the problem starts:

If you stop to the circle, it works perfecly:

```
ST_Buffer(ST_Point(8.54736328125,46.37156925087649)::geography, 3000)::geometry
```

[image]

Than there is the ST_SCALE. This function will shrink the circle to create an ellipse.

It accepts a geometry and a couple of "factor" (xFactor and yFactor).

If you launch it with 1,1, you get the same circle.

```
select ST_AsEWKT( ST_Scale( ST_Buffer(ST_Point(8.54736328125,46.37156925087649)::geography, 3000)::geometry, 1,1)::geometry);
```

If you change the "factors" (for example 0,3 and 0.5), you get an ellipse but its completely translated (in Niger, Africa).

[image]

The original function has a translate after the scale to move back the shape to the original point. I don't know why but using original center coords, I get an Ellipse in Sweden:

```
select ST_AsEWKT(ST_Translate( ST_Rotate( ST_Scale( ST_Buffer(ST_Point(8.54736328125,46.37156925087649)::geography, 3000)::geometry, 0.5,0.3)::geometry, 0), 8.54736328125,46.37156925087649));
```

[image]

I think is a problem about projection and Referring System (the ellipse in sweden is cleary smaller) but im too noobs to understand where to fix.

Comment: ST_Translate uses delta values, not the absolute ones. That means you're moving it **by** 8.54736328125, not **to** 8.54736328125.

Comment: You have used 4326 and 4623 interchangeably in your question, and don't seem to have used either in construction. You ***can't*** convert degrees and meters. It appears you need to construct the ellipse as a circle centered on your point with a custom projection, scale it, rotate it, then deproject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Ellipse in WGS84, but with metric parameters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48636/creating-ellipse-in-wgs84-but-with-metric-parameters)

Comment: The post is the original post where I got the function but as you can see, it doesn't work as it is.

Comment: @Vince The referring system is 4326 (the other was a type error). Im trying to figure out but Scale and translate change the referring system. I have tried to create a circle in 0,0 and than translate (without scale it) to my center and it became an ellipse due to distortion. I don't know how to solve it.